# Find the probability that a string of $100$ lights contains at most four defective bulbs using the Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> A manufacturer of Christmas tree light bulbs knows that $3\%$ of its bulbs are defective. Find the probability that a string of $100$ lights contains at most four defective bulbs using the Poisson distribution.
>
> Source: [Opentextbc.ca](https://opentextbc.ca/introbusinessstatopenstax/chapter/poisson-distribution/)

### My Work So Far

Using the following

$$\begin{align*}
\lambda&=\text{np}\\
&=100(0.03)\\
&=3\\
\\
X &\sim P(3)\\
\end{align*}$$

therefore

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(x\le4)&=\mathbb{P}(x=0)+\mathbb{P}(x=1)+\mathbb{P}(x=2)+\mathbb{P}(x=3)+\mathbb{P}(x=4)\\[5pt]
&=\frac{e^{-3}\times3^0}{0!}+\frac{e^{-3}\times3^1}{1!}+\frac{e^{-3}\times3^2}{2!}+\frac{e^{-3}\times3^3}{3!}+\frac{e^{-3}\times3^4}{4!}\\[5pt]
&=e^{-3}\Bigg\{\frac{3^0}{0!}+\frac{3^1}{1!}+\frac{3^2}{2!}+\frac{3^3}{3!}+\frac{3^4}{4!}\Bigg\}\\[5pt]
&=e^{-3}\left(\frac{131}{8}\right)\\[5pt]
&=\boxed{0.8153}\\[5pt]
\end{align*}$$

which matches the solution on the website. I attempted the same as above, but finding the probability that a string of $100$ lights contains **at least** four defective bulbs, to gain further intuition on this topic

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(x\ge4)&=1-\mathbb{P}(x\le 3)\\[5pt]
&=1-\mathbb{P}(x=0)+\mathbb{P}(x=1)+\mathbb{P}(x=2)+\mathbb{P}(x=3)\\[5pt]
&=\frac{e^{-3}\times3^0}{0!}+\frac{e^{-3}\times3^1}{1!}+\frac{e^{-3}\times3^2}{2!}+\frac{e^{-3}\times3^3}{3!}\\[5pt]
&=e^{-3}\Bigg\{\frac{3^0}{0!}+\frac{3^1}{1!}+\frac{3^2}{2!}+\frac{3^3}{3!}\Bigg\}\\[5pt]
&=0.6472318888\\[5pt]
&=1-0.6472318888\\[5pt]
&=\boxed{0.3528}\\[5pt]
\end{align*}$$

Would both of these methods be correct? The solutions worked in [this calculator](https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Embognar/applets/pois.html), but I just wanted to make sure this is the correct process. Would there also be a better method to derive the solutions?

Comment: As far as I can see, this looks fine, and I think this is the most reasonable way of solving the two problems.

Comment: Your work is correct, but the textbook you are using is awful. It should really emphasize, in the question you're asking, that the distribution is actually binomial, and we're using a Poisson *approximation*. It also calls the Poisson distribution a "waiting time distribution" in the first sentence of the chapter, which is utter nonsense, and can only confuse you when you *do* want a random variable that represents a waiting time.

Comment: Both versions have changed $3$ to $e$, though this is probably your typing rather than calculations

Comment: Your numbers are consistent with the R code `ppois(4,3)` and `1-ppois(3,3)` though the better binomial values would be `pbinom(4,100,0.03)` about $0.8178548$ and `1-pbinom(3,100,0.03)` about $0.3527508$